# Rails 6 + Webpacker + jQuery + jGrowl is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I am using Rails 6. I am having problems with getting js plugins working. I am trying to add jGrowl.

This what I have tried:

```
yarn install jgrowl
```

This is how my application.js file looks like:

```
import 'jquery'
import 'jgrowl'
```

This is how my environment.js file looks like:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize jQuery. Add the following code to `application.js`

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = jQuery
window.jQuery = jQuery
```